# Get flash drive to cache disk reads to primary partition

Tags: performance, usb-drive, cache

Basically I'm looking for a way to mimic Windows' ReadyBoost.

I asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/linux-equivalent-to-readyboost) on Unix.SE to get an idea of whether this was even possible and it seems like it is. Appparently there is a `cachefs` filesystem I can use to do this.

- Flash drive: `/dev/sdc1` (fs: `vfat`)
- Main partition: `/dev/sda5` (fs: `ext4`)

How can I configure Ubuntu to do this?

Comment: It seems rather strange that your primary partition for your system is vfat and not ext4

Comment: @Reuben: Ooops. I got them mixed up. Sorry.

Comment: Wish you'd mentioned that you wanted the root partition earlier; that gets trickier, although I'd suspect that sufficiently evil `initrd`/`pivot_root` hackery could make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible.  CacheFiles has only been implemented for NFS so far.  Another upcoming possibility is CleanCache.  Currently CleanCache only has two backends: one for xen tmem, and one for storing cached pages in compressed ram.  Hopefully a third backend will be written to store the cached pages on block devices like flash drives.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, it looks like it might be fairly easy.  `apt-get install cachefilesd` and read the documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, after reading the `man` page, I am still having a bit of trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Have you actually tried it geekosaur? man page says it's for caching network filesystems... I found someone mounting nfs on 127.0.0.1 to use it, but no performance analysis.